# How do you loop AVPlayer in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I have used the following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(ViewController.restartVideoFromBeginning),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,object: nil)

@objc func restartVideoFromBeginning()  {


    let seconds : Int64 = 0
    let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 1
    let seekTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, preferredTimeScale)

    player!.seek(to: seekTime)

    player!.play()

}
```

But the player inside `restartVideoFromBeginning` has a nil value, does anyone know why?

Comment: is your player playing 1st time, right?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper

Comment: Yes. it is playing the firs time.

Answer (score 10):

I tried this and it worked

Loop the video

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: myPlayer.currentItem, queue: nil) { (_) in
            myPlayer.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            myPlayer.play()
}
myPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(avLayer)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2 below. I'd look into AVPlayerLooper first though.

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (_) in
        player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        player.play()
    }
```